# split a column of delimited text in multiple columns

Tags: linux, awk, sed, bioinformatics

### I have a file like present below.

```
chr1     15431658     A     T      GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL           0/1:15,20:35:66:211,0,222
```

---

I want to have an output where I can split 6th column delimited by ":". How can I do this in awk.

### This is the output I want

```
chr1    15431658   A   T    GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL      0/1   15,20   35   66   211,0,222
```

---

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: How the heck did this question get upvoted at least 3 times??? And it's got answers!!! smh...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -F"[[:space:]]+" '{gsub(/:/,"\t",$NF)} 1' OFS="\t"   Input_file
```

Comment: better than mine since it works even for a different number of columns! ;-) We still don't know which `OFS` should be used though hahaha

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following `awk` command:

```
echo 'chr1     15431658     A     T      GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL           0/1:15,20:35:66:211,0,222' | awk '{$6=gensub(/:/,"\t","g",$6); print $0}' | column -t
chr1  15431658  A  T  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1  15,20  35  66  211,0,222
```

You can replace `\t` by as many space as you need in the replacement call, last but not least since it is not specified in your post if you want `tab` separated columns or space separated columns. I have not taken this into account, you can configure this by changing your `awk` command in the following way (`OFS="YOUR SEPARATOR"`):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$6=gensub(/:/,"\t","g",$6); print $0}'
```